# Xcode crashes when adding folder reference from another project in shared workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

•I have a workspace

•Inside are 3 projects:
    -Banana app
    -Pineapple app
    -CKKit-a master library that has reusable base feature both apps share and inherit from.

•When I add files to the master library, I used to be able to just delete the old folder reference in both apps and then just drag the CKKit folder as a reference to both projects.

•Ever since updating x-code to 9.1 this causes an immediate crash.

•I have reported it to Apple all 48 times that it has occurred to me over the last month or 2, but now I'm desperate for a solution.